# Why does my CSS disappear when I go from index.html to index.html/#contact?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a link that will go in the section `contact` in my HTML file.

For instance, when I'm in `abc.html` and I click on this:

```
<a href="index.html/#contact>Go to contact</a>
```

it redirects me to here:

```
<div id="contact">
<h1>Contact</h1>
</div>
```

But when I arrive the css is not linked! And I don't understand why?...

But when I go to `index.html`, the css is okay.

This is what I have in the `head` of my `index.html` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: its because you have another slash after index.html, that changes relative pathing

Comment: Use absolute paths in your index.html file. Example `/css/style.css` (this is absolute path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it like this!!!

```
<a href="index.html#contact>Go to contact</a>
<div id="contact">
  ...
</div>
```

and also avoid `...` before the path if you are not stepping back just do it like this `css/style.css`